# How to convert date from mongodb to JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I have a mongodb set up and I'm storing date and time alongside other data. The problem is that when I receive the data back the date and time is in a strange format and I'm not sure how I can handle this with JavaScript or jQuery.

my schema:

```
var carSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    carType: String,
    notes: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

this is what I'm getting in the JavaScript object:

```
created: "2015-03-15T14:01:16.447Z"
```

How can I convert this to Time and date?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: it's a valid date string anyway: `var d=new Date("2015-03-15T14:01:16.447Z"); alert(d.toLocaleString())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i am giving some snippet of codes which will assist to getting your requirement.

```
var created_date = new Date(carSchema.created);

var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var year = created_date.getFullYear();
var month = months[created_date.getMonth()];
var date = created_date.getDate();
var hour = created_date.getHours();
var min = created_date.getMinutes();
var sec = created_date.getSeconds();
var time = date + ',' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;    // final date with time, you can use this according your requirement



Or

var timestamp = created_date.getTime();    // get time stamp, now you can convert date and time from it using simple JavaScript function
```

You can use time() npm to reset timezone for this

```
var time = require('time');

created_date.setTimezone("Australia/Sydney");
```

Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks. However, you need to create a for loop i < 10 to add zeros in seconds, minutes and hours otherwise you will get time like this: 11:3:4 instead of 11:03:04

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var myNewJSDateObj = new Date(carSchema.created);
var someOtherDateTimeVar = myNewJSDateObj.to...
```

where:

```
myNewJSDateObj.toDateString(        myNewJSDateObj.toLocaleDateString(  myNewJSDateObj.toString(            myNewJSDateObj.tojson(
myNewJSDateObj.toGMTString(         myNewJSDateObj.toLocaleString(      myNewJSDateObj.toTimeString(
myNewJSDateObj.toISOString(         myNewJSDateObj.toLocaleTimeString(  myNewJSDateObj.toUTCString(
```